# Application with onItemClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, onitemclicklistener

I am making an application. I want to get some information out of a Json file on the web. This works. Now i want to have an onItemClickListener to the items of the listview with the content. The onItemClickListener must send the information of the clicked list to my new activity.

The code of my MainActiviy.java is:

```
package com.jitesh.androidjsonparser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private Context context;
    private static String url = "http://docs.blackberry.com/sampledata.json"; // URL VAN HET JSON BESTAND

    private static final String TAG_VTYPE = "vehicleType"; //VELDEN UIT DE JSON HALEN
    private static final String TAG_VCOLOR = "vehicleColor";
    private static final String TAG_FUEL = "fuel";
    private static final String TAG_TREAD = "treadType";
    private static final String TAG_OPERATOR = "approvedOperators";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_POINTS = "experiencePoints";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ProgressTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
    }

    private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        private ListActivity activity;

        // private List<Message> messages;
        public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
            context = activity;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */

        /** application context. */
        private Context context;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_VTYPE, TAG_VCOLOR,
                            TAG_FUEL, TAG_TREAD }, new int[] {
                            R.id.vehicleType, R.id.vehicleColor, R.id.fuel,
                            R.id.treadType });

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            // selecting single ListView item
             lv = getListView();             
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String vtype = c.getString(TAG_VTYPE);

                    String vcolor = c.getString(TAG_VCOLOR);
                    String vfuel = c.getString(TAG_FUEL);
                    String vtread = c.getString(TAG_TREAD);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_VTYPE, vtype);
                    map.put(TAG_VCOLOR, vcolor);
                    map.put(TAG_FUEL, vfuel);
                    map.put(TAG_TREAD, vtread);
                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }


    }

}
```

Can anyone help me with the onItemClickListener and on which place i must set this onItemClickListener?

```
@Override protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {       
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), single_list_item_view.class);     
         String vehicleType = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();   
         i.putExtra("TAG_VTYPE", vehicleType); 
         startActivity(i); 
 }
```

Comment: use this link-  may help you, -[this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: You probably want to research http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are extending `ListActivity`, so you do not need `onItemClickListener`. You can directly override `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)`. This method will be called when an item in the list is selected.

As you did with onCreate, you can do the same for `onListItemClick`

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, single_list_item_view.class);     
    HashMap<String, String> itemPressed = (HashMap<String, String>)l.getItemAtPosition(position); 
    String vehicleType = itemPressed.get(TAG_VTYPE);   
     i.putExtra("TAG_VTYPE", vehicleType); 
     startActivity(i); 
}
```

Comment: I am new to android, so can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I have placed this code now, but it doesn't work. My application crashed if I click on a listitem.
`@Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), single_list_item_view.class);
  String vehicleType = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
  // sending data to new activity
        i.putExtra("TAG_VTYPE", vehicleType);
        startActivity(i); 
 }`

Comment: what does happen? Does your app crash or what?

Comment: Yes i have an fatal error, and the app closed. I have to close the app with forced close.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but the application crashed also on this code. I think I must changethe Listview l to Listview lv? But after that the application doesn't work too.

Comment: can you check the error in the logcat? Did you add `single_list_item_view` in the manifest?

Comment: is `single_list_item_view` an Activity?

Comment: That's the problem indeed. It was not an activity, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create hashmap arraylist.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                  String name =urarraylist.get(position).get("name");// here you have to pas keynawhich is put inyour Hashmap arraylist

                  Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),anotheractivity.class);
                  i.putExtra("name", name);

                  startActivity(i); 
                }
            });
```